# Question based on logarithm inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\log_{2x+3}(x+4)>-1$
What I did:-
 Firstly I calculated the domain
$(x+4)>0$
$x>-4$
In the solution it is given that,
$(2x+3)>0$ and $2x+3\neq1$
Why are we doing this when we have already calculated the domain and also why $2x+3\neq1$?
Can anyone please help me out with question? I am very weak at logarithm inequalities and I will be really glad if anyone of you will solve my query.

Comment: Try to use $\log_{a}{b}=\dfrac{\ln{b}}{\ln{a}}$

Answer (score 1):

rewriting your inequality we get
$$\frac{\ln(x+4)}{\ln(2x+3)}>-1$$
for $$2x+3>1$$ we get
$$\ln(x+4)>-\ln(2x+3)$$
this is equivalent to
$$\ln(x+4)>\ln((2x+3)^{-1})$$
can you finish?
this is equivalent to $$2x^2+11x+11>0$$
comparing this with $$x>-1$$ we get $$x>-1$$ as the solutionset:
in the second case $$0<2x+3<1$$ we obtain
$$-\frac{3}{2}<x<\frac{1}{4}\left(-11+\sqrt{33}\right)$$

Comment: Did you intend to write $x>-1$ rather than $x>1$ for the first part of the answer?

Comment: it should be $$x>-1$$ sorry

Answer (score 0):

For logarithms, we require the base to be positive and non-unit. That is, negative-based logarithms don't make sense and base-one logs are - well, not useful.

Answer (score 0):

We need to solve
$$\log_{2x+3}(x+4)+1>0$$ or
$$\log_{2x+3}(x+4)(2x+3)>0.$$

The domain gives $2x+3>0$, $2x+3\neq1$ and $x+4>0$.

If $2x+3>1$ we have $(2x+3)(x+4)>1$;

if $0<2x+3<1$ we have $(2x+3)(x+4)<1$.

Now we need to solve these systems.